# Render a View inside a View in Asp.Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I render a full fledged view (not partial view) inside another view?

Scenario, I have different controller and want the exactly same view to render which is already there under other controller with different layout.

I have Wishlist page in Home Controller which shows list of added products, and when user logged in , when I click on wish list it also show me navigation when user is signed in.

How would I do that??

Comment: Did you try like View("ViewName", Model);....?

Comment: I want to do this from .cshtml file

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151182/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-a-view-from-another-view-in-mvc

Comment: PartialView with ChildActionOnly is your answer  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Denys solved my issue.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Not many developers know about this but you can use [RenderPage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in), it's specifically designed for that purpose(to render an MVC view inside another view)

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/SampleView.cshtml")
```

Comment: Well Done Denys, this is exacly what Qadeer is looking for, I have tested this in a application and it works. did not test this with models but i am sure it will work. well done...

Comment: exactly, I wanted this

Comment: This is not for asp.net core at least in 2.0. Use @Html.Partial instead.

Answer (score 14):

You can still create or use a partial view with its own controller and use the [RenderAction()](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/)

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ActionPartialView(string p1)

{
    //code...

    return PartialView(); 
}
```

The above code can be in any controller, its own controller, just call it in razor with that controller.

Razor:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Home"); }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What about parameters inside call for action Index?